# Can you explain this behavior with Python defaultdict and autovivification

Tags: python, defaultdict

I'm not sure if I'm missing something trivially obvious here but I can't for the life of me work out how the code below manages to give the output it does.

```
import collections

tree = collections.defaultdict(dict)
tree[0][1] = tree[1]
print tree
tree[1][2] = tree[2]
print tree
```

And here's the magical output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {0: {1: {}}, 1: {}})
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {0: {1: {2: {}}}, 1: {2: {}}, 2: {}})
```

The first line of output makes total sense. Consider then, the assignment `tree[1][2] = tree[2]` and its subsequent output.

I understand that the entry `2: {}`  has been created by evaluating the RHS expression `tree[2]`.

I also understand the the entry `1: {2: {}}` is created be evaluating the LHS expression `tree[1][2]` and assigning it to the value of the RHS.

What I don't understand, is how the dictionary entry `0: {1: {}}` has been updated to `0: {1: {2: {}}}` when no reference to `tree[0]` was made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you do `tree[0][1] = tree[1]` , `tree[0][1]` is referencing the same object as `tree[1]` , so if any changes happen inside `tree[1]` , it will also reflect in `tree[0][1]`.

And, when you do `tree[1][2]` , you are actually making changes inside `tree[1]` , and not making `tree[1]` reference a new object.

Example , after your changes try to do this -

```
>>> tree[1]['blah'] = 'Hello'
>>> print(tree)
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {0: {1: {2: {}, 'blah': 'Hello'}}, 1: {2: {}, 'blah': 'Hello'}, 2: {}})
```

Only if you do something like - `tree[1] = <somethingelse>` , you are making `tree[1]` reference a new object, in which case it would not reflect in `tree[0][1]` .

Comment: OK, I guess the source of confusion here is the print output not including the object reference. The output `0: {1: {}}` implies that the entry is empty, not that it contains a reference to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of objects (not primitives) are stored as references, not values. So if you assign a to b, then change a, b also changes.